# Java generics: required capture#67 of?

Tags: java, generics

I have this function:

```
 /**
 * Helper function that adds the values of b to the elements of a, treating
 * all keys that exist in b but not in a, as existent in a with value 0. NB:
 * It operates IN PLACE. 
 * @param a The {@link java.util.Map} which will hold the result
 * @param b The {@link java.util.Map} which will be added to a
 */
private static void sumMaps(Map<?, Integer> a, Map<?,Integer> b)
{
    for (Object key : b.keySet()) {
        Integer currentCount = a.get(key);
        a.put(key, currentCount == null ? b.get(key) : currentCount + b.get(key));
    }
}
```

However, NetBeans highlights "key" in the final line of for, and gives me this error:

```
method put in class java.util.Map<K,V> cannot be applied to given types  
required: capture #67 of?, java.lang.Integer  
found: java.lang.Object, int
```

(the int is not the problem because of Java unpacking, I tried using Integers too but it didn't work).

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your answers, they all suggest roughly the same thing, so I acepted one practically at random.

Comment: Note `Map.entrySet` will give you a more efficient way to iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying "?" for the key means that it could be of any type, but the keys must be the same for each Map for this method to work. So use the following instead:

```
private static <K> void sumMaps(Map<K, Integer> a, Map<K, Integer> b) {
        for (K key : b.keySet()) {
            Integer currentCount = a.get(key);
            a.put(key, currentCount == null ? b.get(key) : currentCount + b.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried a generic type, but I got a "class not found: K" error. I didn't know I could "declare" the type before void. This was a very simple question after all.

Comment: You can make that slightly more general. The first map key can be a base type of the second map key.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is one of covariance. When you pull a key out of one map you cannot guarantee that the key is compatible with the other map. If one map uses `Foo`s and the other map uses `Bar`s and these two classes are unrelated to each other then you cannot interchange them.

Imagine that a is of type `Map<String, Integer>` and b is of type `Map<Float, Integer>`. These two types are compatible with your parameter declarations, but their key types are incompatible. You will have trouble if you take a `Float` from b and try to use it as a key in `a.put(key,...)`. That is effectively what the compiler is complaining about. Using `?` does not restrict the maps to compatible key types.

Instead of `?` you must specify that the two key classes are the same by setting them both to some generic `Key` class. This way the keys from one map can be inserted into the keys from the other map.

```
private static <Key> void sumMaps(Map<Key, Integer> a, Map<Key, Integer> b)
{
    for (Key key : b.keySet()) {
        Integer currentCount = a.get(key);
        a.put(key, currentCount == null ? b.get(key) : currentCount + b.get(key));
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, if you're trying to suss out a problem with `?`, do **not** mentally replace `?` with `Object`. Instead, a better way to think about it is to replace every instance of `?` with a different imaginary type name.

**Warning: Math Analogy**

It's similar to the *C* constant that shows up in indefinite integrals in calculus. For instance, ∫ cos *x* d*x* = sin *x* + *C*. If you do one integral then writing *C* is fine, but if you do multiple integrals then you have to remember that these constants are different and are not interchangeable. It then behooves you to write *C*<sub>1</sub>, *C*<sub>2</sub>, *C*<sub>3</sub>, etc.

`?` is the same way. The first time it shows up, pretend it is `class A`. The next time it is `class B`. And so on.

Comment: Even though it's valid - I think I'd prefer `<K>` over `<Key>`, `Key` looks to much like a class name but it is a type variable.

Comment: Since you bring it up, I find it sort of puzzling that convention is to use names like `T`, `K`, and `V`. It seems to me that this is a C++ convention that should have been dropped, in the same way that Java dropped other forms of abbreviation in favor of fully spelled out words.

Comment: John - it's probably because there's no difference in usage between generic parameters and "real" class names.  Since the generic parameter usage is always lexically local, it's usually fine to give them single-letter names and this functions well as a naming convention that distinguishes them from actual classes.  When I look at your (correct) code snippet, my brain naturally interprets `Key` as an actual class whereas it would interpret `K` as a generic parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`?` is not `Object` or something. It's totally unknown. Okay, I'm not that good at explaining that stuff either but there seems to be a very simple solution: Since the keys of both `Map`s need to be of the same type anyway why not introduce a generic type variable?

```
private static <T> void sumMaps(Map<T, Integer> a, Map<T, Integer> b) {
    for (T key : b.keySet()) {
        Integer currentCount = a.get(key);
        a.put(key, currentCount == null ? b.get(key) : currentCount
                + b.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `?` read "some *particular* type" and note that this could be a different type each time you mention `?`.  So, for example, `a` could be a `Map<String, Integer>` and `b` could be a `Map<BigDecimal, Integer>`.  So, indeed, you shouldn't be allowed to take a key out of `a` and put it into `b` and the compiler is stopping you.  The compiler isn't very helpful in explaining this!

As other answers have suggested, you could make the method generic.

Answer (score 1):

Object is not a valid substitute for ?.
Here is a working version with a type variable T:

```
private static <T> void sumMaps(final Map<T, Integer> a,
    final Map<T, Integer> b){
    for(final T key : b.keySet()){
        final Integer currentCount = a.get(key);
        a.put(key,
            currentCount == null
                ? b.get(key)
                : Integer.valueOf(currentCount.intValue()
                    + b.get(key).intValue()));
    }
}
```

(I also removed some auto-boxing / unboxing)

Comment: Why would you remove auto-boxing? I used it on purpose.

Comment: Because I belong to the group of people who believes that autoboxing is an awful feature that causes many expected bugs (I always set my eclipse warning level to warning or error for autoboxing).